# how to send a properly formatted html mail using mail function php

Tags: php, html, email

hello i am trying to send an email using mail function in php, from my search iv read that to send html enabld emails we need to pass an argument to the headers stateing the presence of html tags is to be passed, which i am doing using this

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

i have sent this to my mail headers but my email in which i am need to display a table of dynamic contents and a hyperlink isnt formatted, it is so scattered.

this is my full code

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = '###'; 
$dbpass = '###'; 
$dbname = '###'; 

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
if(!$conn) { 
die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db($dbname); 

$sql="SELECT Insured_Name,Expiry_Date FROM transactions  
WHERE MONTH(Expiry_Date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) and YEAR(Expiry_Date) = YEAR(CURDATE())"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die("Cannot query orders_products data" . mysql_error()); 



$email = "###############"; 
$emailto = "############"; 
$subject = "List of policies to expire this month"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$headers = "From: $email"; 

// prepare email body text 
$body .= "Here Are A List Of policies to expire this month\n\n";
$body .= "<a href='expired.php'>Download complete list</a>\n\n";
$body .='<table width="200" border="1">';
$body .='<tr>';
 $body .='<td>Insured name</td>';
    $body .='<td>Expiry date</td>';
  $body .='</tr>';


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$body .='<tr>';
 $body .='<td>'.$row['Insured_Name'] .'</td>';
 $body .='<td>'.$row['Expiry_Date'] .'</td>';

  $body .='</tr>';

} 
$body .='</table>';
$body .= "This is an automated mail from the KBL insurance portal\n\n";
// send email 
$send = mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers); 

mysql_close($conn); 

// redirect to success page 

?>
```

please is there anything i am doing wrongly here?

Answer (score 0):

From PHP [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: If you use Linux, remove "\r"

Comment: from this alone "$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; " or every where it is used

Comment: Unix OS use '\n' - line feed -  as a line separator; Windows use '\r\n' as a line separator and Mac use '\r'  - carriage
 return - as the line separator. Mac OS X uses '\n'